# how to use projection in the include extension method in ef core?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I want to able to select certain entity properties (columns from db) in the include statement of queryable object. My query looks like below but I m getting error `Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid`

```
  var samuraiWithQuotesQueryable = _context.Samurais.AsQueryable()
            .Include(s => s.Quotes.Select(x => new { x.Text }));

   // additional filters followed by getting the list
     
  var samuraiList = samuraiWithQuotesQueryable.ToList();
```

Samurai and Quote entities look like below

```
 public class Samurai
 {

   public Samurai()
   {
     Quotes = new List<Quote>();
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }

 }

public class Quote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Samurai Samurai { get; set; }
    public int SamuraiId { get; set; }
}
```

Wondering if this is possible with the IQueryable object?

Comment: You need to just include the entire entity, and then use `Select` to project your entire query into new objects

Comment: This is not possible as this is just not what `.Include()` is supposed to do - Include just tells EF which related entities shall be loaded from the database. Looking at your code the question is: Where would you expect `new { x.Text }` to be in the `Samurai` object? its not of type `Quote` so it certainly cannot be in the `Quotes` list. So this won't be possible as you could not access the data even if it was loaded. Is there a reason why you don't want to include the whole `Quote` object? Regarding performance it would hardly make a difference as it just has an additional id property...

Comment: @Nannanas The above entities are just short examples, the actual entities I m working with, have plenty of properties and really slow down the query. All I m trying is to load only properties that I need in the navigation list.

Comment: @rumi Then you have to project the whole entity into an anonymous object like so `context.Samurais.Select(samurai => new { samurai, Quotes = smaurai.Quotes.Select(quote => quote.Text)})`